# Android Studio GitHub Login "Incorrect credentials. Request response. 401 Unauthorized

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I am having trouble logging in to my GitHub Account through Android Studio. I don't know why I am getting this error and there doesn't seem to be much about it out there. I made sure to have Git Installed and even tried doing this using a token. See attached images. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

[image: Login credentails]

[image: Token]

Answer (score 15):

I have same issue and just solved it.
I'm using Android Studio 4.1

I try using [Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and select scopes needed for android studio [Token Scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PoC6.png).
In Android Studio GitHub setting login using token, enter "http://github.com" (not "github.com") and generated token in the provided field then click log in.

My login was succeed with that setup.

Comment: Worked for me as well. The key is in the "http://github.com", it's really frustrating that it wouldn't just auto fill to that. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: For me, generating a personal access token for Androidstudio with the suggested scopes was sufficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

When you generate your token

1. **repo** - select everything
2. **gist** - select  everything
3. **org**  - select only **read:org**

and generate your token. Now you can add your account. It is work for me.

Comment: this, plus " http: //github. com" instead of "github.com" did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When generate a new token in your git hub profile, select  repo  gist and read:org.
It worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]
After copying, open the use token  and paste !